# Splashscreen с горизонтальным progressBar с использованием корутин

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

Я пытаюсь создать загрузочный экран с горизонтальным progressBar. Я хочу создать его с помощью сопрограмм. Вот мой код:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)
        progressBarLoading = findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(1000)
            if (progressBarStatus < 100) {
                progressBarLoading?.setProgress(progressBarStatus)
                progressBarStatus = progressBarStatus + 30

            } else {
                var intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

но этот код работает некорректно. ProgressBar не движется и нет перехода на следующий экран. Т е экран просто висит и ничего не происходит.

Comment: Код не работает, потому что создавать искусственную задержку - [плохо](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/312516/) (шутка).

Comment: @ Вася Воронцов , так без задержки экрана вообще не будет